# Как извлечь координаты из строки (x1;y1)(x2;y2)?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка с координатами:

```
(x1;y1)(x2;y2)
```

Как можно извлечь каждую координату?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/4ojni2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию sscanf

```
$s = '(55.456867;45.234544)(60.546345;54.325633)';
sscanf($s, '(%f;%f)(%f;%f)', $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
echo $x1.' '.$y1."\n".$x2.' '.$y2;
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/022a01b4c69d087feb510f212ac2430487bca18d)

Answer (score 1):

Была у программиста проблема, решил он воспользоваться регулярным выражением и вот...теперь у него две проблемы) Предлагаю решение подобного вида.

```
    $input = "(55.456867;45.234544)(60.546345;54.325633)(55.4535867;45.2365444)(60.546345;54.3235333)(55.4567;45.2342)(60.234;54.12312312)(55.3457;45.6456)(60.86447;54.262673)";
    $input = rtrim (ltrim ($input, '('), ')');

    $inputArray = explode (')(', $input);

    foreach ($inputArray as $cord) {
        $cords[] = explode (';', $cord);
    }

    var_dump ($cords);
```

---

На выходе получите:

```
array(8) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "55.456867" [1]=> string(9) "45.234544" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "60.546345" [1]=> string(9) "54.325633" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "55.4535867" [1]=> string(10) "45.2365444" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "60.546345" [1]=> string(10) "54.3235333" } [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "55.4567" [1]=> string(7) "45.2342" } [5]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "60.234" [1]=> string(11) "54.12312312" } [6]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "55.3457" [1]=> string(7) "45.6456" } [7]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "60.86447" [1]=> string(9) "54.262673" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\(([0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+){0,1});([0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+){0,1})\)
```

выбирается из (55.456867;45.234544) в группе 1: `55.456867` в группе 2: `45.234544`.

Под совпадение не попадут координаты `(55.;45.)`, но попадут `(55333;45333)`.

Пример [тут](https://regex101.com/r/NdAZew/5).

Answer (score -1):

У меня такой вариант получился: (Пользовался этим сайтом: https://regex101.com/)

**(\d+[.,]?\d+)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]